# Spliting a week of data in to days of the Week SQL

Tags: sql, t-sql

Good Morning All
So I was asked to look where things are getting ordered from on a weekly bases so simple.

```
DECLARE @vYearWeek INT
SET @vYearWeek = '201745';

SELECT
  LEFT(Orders.ProductWhsLocation,1) AS 'Area',
  COUNT(Orders.HostOrderNo) AS 'Picked'
FROM CHDS_Common.dbo.OMOrder Orders
  LEFT JOIN CHDS_Management.dbo.Calendar Cal ON CONVERT(date, Orders.EarliestPickDate) = Cal.DT 
  WHERE Orders.PicksetNo <> 0 AND cal.YWK = @vYearWeek
  GROUP BY LEFT(ProductWhsLocation,1)
  ORDER BY LEFT(ProductWhsLocation,1);
```

And this works fine ... how ever I need to got deeper now and spilt it in to days. Now logic would say this will be simple as:

```
DECLARE @vYearWeek INT
SET @vYearWeek = '201745';

SELECT
  LEFT(Orders.ProductWhsLocation,1) AS 'Area',
  CASE WHEN Cal.DW = 1 THEN COUNT(Orders.HostOrderNo) ELSE 0 END AS 'Sunday',
  CASE WHEN Cal.DW = 2 THEN COUNT(Orders.HostOrderNo) ELSE 0 END AS 'Monday',
  CASE WHEN Cal.DW = 3 THEN COUNT(Orders.HostOrderNo) ELSE 0 END AS 'Tuesday',
  CASE WHEN Cal.DW = 4 THEN COUNT(Orders.HostOrderNo) ELSE 0 END AS 'Wednesday',
  CASE WHEN Cal.DW = 5 THEN COUNT(Orders.HostOrderNo) ELSE 0 END AS 'Thuresday',
  CASE WHEN Cal.DW = 6 THEN COUNT(Orders.HostOrderNo) ELSE 0 END AS 'Friday',
  CASE WHEN Cal.DW = 7 THEN COUNT(Orders.HostOrderNo) ELSE 0 END AS 'Saturday'
FROM CHDS_Common.dbo.OMOrder Orders
  LEFT JOIN CHDS_Management.dbo.Calendar Cal ON CONVERT(date, Orders.EarliestPickDate) = Cal.DT 
WHERE Orders.PicksetNo <> 0 AND cal.YWK = @vYearWeek
GROUP BY LEFT(ProductWhsLocation,1)
ORDER BY LEFT(ProductWhsLocation,1);
```

But as you all know ERROR :( 
Column 'CHDS_Management.dbo.Calendar.DW' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Any Help on sorting this out would be great many thanks all.

Comment: did u tried using cal.dw in group by ?

Comment: I tried this it clears the error but the results are all over.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pivot Query would work in this scenario

--Improved Answer

step1: Get day of week either by date in calendar table or day number

step 2: use pivot table to get count of rows by day

```
SELECT *

FROM
(
    SELECT
  LEFT(Orders.ProductWhsLocation,1) AS 'Area',
  COUNT(Orders.HostOrderNo) OrderCount,
  DATENAME(weekday,cal.dt) 'DayName'
  FROM CHDS_Common.dbo.OMOrder Orders
  LEFT JOIN CHDS_Management.dbo.Calendar Cal ON CONVERT(date, Orders.EarliestPickDate) = Cal.DT 
WHERE Orders.PicksetNo <> 0 AND cal.YWK = @vYearWeek
GROUP BY LEFT(ProductWhsLocation,1),cal.dw
) AS SourceTable PIVOT(SUM(OrderCount) FOR [DayName] IN([SUNDAY]
                                                        ,[MONDAY]
                                                        ,[TUESDAY]
                                                        ,[WEDNESDAY]
                                                        ,[THURSDAY]
                                                        ,[FRIDAY]
                                                        ,[SATURDAY] )
                                                        
) AS PivotTable;
```

Comment: getting an Error on     FOR 'DayName' IN   As  Incorrect syntax near 'DayName' trying to work out why

Comment: removed quotes and replaced with []

Comment: Thank you so much thats looking a lot more like it now :)

Comment: Going to look out how to order the pivot now just to make it tidy!

Comment: Thanks for the Help used the same methord for the whole reportnow!

Comment: @JustinGreenwood thats good to know. It would be worth of exploring more into pivot and unpivot.